# Is it possible to assign different attributes to different characters in a string in UITextView?Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, nsmutableattributedstring

I placed a large text in a UITextView In Xcode in interface builder. Is it possible to assign different attributes (colors, headings, alignments..etc) to different parts of the string. Using `MutableAttributedString` would not work for me since the string is longer than 5000 words, it would take ages to format it.

[image]

Comment: yea! possible if you doing pragmatically :)

Comment: If I remember well you can do it in XCode, but it's not "easy" (especially when you do a mistake to correct it): Select part of the text, and then change the font, etc. To change line, do it with Alt+Enter, etc. Else, you can enter open the file as Source File, and mofify yourself the xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple way to do this. Outside Xcode :)

Open `TextEditor` in `MAC` and paste your text into it and format it as per your requirement and again copy it.

Now Add your `UITextView` into your `ViewController` in `Storyboard` and make that textView Attributed.

Now Paste your formatted text there in the text field.

Check below screenshot for reference.

[image]

[image]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: that's a nice hack. I will still wait to see if anyone else can do it in Xcode, though I doubt, and then I will accept your answer since this workaround provides the desired result.